# Designing layouts for phones and tablets

Tags: android

Okay i am familiar with this site and what it says

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

But im still having a problem.

I am designing layouts for phones and tablets from gingerbread to jelly bean.

I had started with a basic layout folder and designed everything for a galaxy nexus phone. now im going back and adding tablets. one question here is should i use layout-xlarge/layout-large or layout-sw600dp/layout-sw720dp? im guessing the smallest width is what i should be using.

But thats not the issue.
This issue is im trying to do that layous for Galaxy Nexus (720x1280) and Nexus S (480x800) These are much different yet eclipse doesn't seem to let me differentiate.

So i just want to be clear on what i should be doing to do this right. is this what i should have to cover the devices i want to?

layout-hdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-sw600dp (instead of layout-large)
layout-sw720dp (instead of layout-xlarge)

will doing those layout-hdpi and layout-xhdpi separate the layouts for a Nexus S and Galaxy Nexus?

Comment: The reason Eclipse doesn't let you differentiate is because the size mostly affects the layout and any background image (if it's just one large file taking the entire space of the layout). For the smaller images, icons, and everything drawable-related that don't take up the entire screen, make sure to use the density-specific folders, and that you use independent pixels for those drawables in your ImageViews/Drawables/java code/xml. The Android system will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the layout-sw are based on `dp`, Density-independent pixels, rather than pixels. You can think of `dp` as 'actual size' pixels i.e., 1dp is the same physical size no matter what device is being used.

Therefore the Galaxy Nexus, which has a 720x1280 pixel screen is only 360x640 dp resolution and there is no overlap between a phone and the higher sw600+ folders.

The large/xlarge buckets will continue to work on all tablets, but if you need finer grained support or alright only using tablet layouts on Android 3.2+ devices, then you only need the sw--dp folders. You can also use both without copy/pasting your XML by using a reference file, as detailed in the below blog post.

More details on how to support multiple screens can be found in [Supporting Multiple Screens guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and some of the reasoning behind why you'd want to use the new sw---dp buckets can be found [on the Android Developers blog post announcing the feature](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html).

Comment: okay, thanks for the clarification. I understand the tablet layouts now. BUT im still having issue with the phones. while im building layout in eclipse i can switch view from one device to next. I have have one on my layout xmls from layout folder (which should work for nexus s and galaxy nexus?) it over laps on nexus s. there is not enough vertical spacing. on the galaxy nexus everything is just right, but when i switch to nexus s i get overlapping for whatever reason. i have to separate these so i don't get that overlap, right?

Comment: @BigDX - yes, generally the same layout is used for all phones. Make sure your layouts are using `wrap_content` as much as possible - that way they will automatically grow in size based on their content. Remember that users can override some things at a system level (like font size) so your layouts need to be flexible enough to support that. I would ask a separate question and post your XML if you continue to have issues with overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `layout-large` and `layout-xlarge`.  When you're developing the layouts and want to know what it looks like on a certain device, just change the view and it will pull the appropriate XML from the correct folder.

Comment: It would have been better if the downvoter explained why this is downvoted.

Comment: I just did. Not because it is great answer, but I didn't agree with down vote you got. :--)